# Using custom condition on smart-table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, search, smart-table

How can I add a custom search condition to a smart table ?

Usually, we set the search for a column like this :

```
<input st-search="description" placeholder="Description..." type="search"/>
```

But is there a way to use a custom function for the search ?
Using `st-set-filter` will change the behavior of `st-search` and this is not what I want.

For now, I'm adding the condition when building the table lines like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="request in r.displayedRequests"
    ng-if="r.isInArray(r.developersList, request.developers && (request.status != 'CAN')">
    <td>{{request.id}}</td>
    <td>{{request.description}}</td>
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Doing this filters the proper lines but this makes the pagination fail, since the `displayedRequests` is not updated like when using `st-search`.

So, how can I add a condition using my controller variables to filter my table lines ?

(And still being able to filter by global or column search using `st-search` on different text inputs)

Comment: you want to run a function on the controller after the user enters a query inside an `input` with st-search?

Answer (score 0):

> Doing this filters the proper lines but this makes the pagination fail

you should really not filter your table rows using `ng-if` when using `ng-repeat`. ng-repeat expressions can take their own filter arguments and can accept your own custom filters.

```
ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter: thoseIDislike"
```

this will also kill your pagination, so use the `st-safe-src` directive to save a safe copy of your data and repeat by it

[sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gu59Vu?p=preview)

> But is there a way to use a custom function for the search ?

yes, you can use `ng-change` on the `input`, when you will change the input's model value, the function will run (to prevent it from running on each key stroke, i'm using `ng-model-option`'s debounce property)

```
<input st-search="firstName" 
            placeholder="first name" 
            ng-model="fname" 
            ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" 
            ng-change="alertMe(fname)">
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.alertMe = function(message) {
  if (message.length>0) {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm trying to do, there is no input to use. I want to add a condition using function and variable in my controller. I'm already using `st-safe-src`. But not using `st-search` doesn't update my `displayedRequest`

Comment: then use filters and click handlers like ng-click or ng-change, using ng-if on table rows would remove those rows from the DOM, and that's already what ng-repeat does when filtered.
in my answer `thoseIDislike` is a condition, it can also be a boolean value